# How to fix plot issue with seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot confusion matrix for mnist dataset but the plot is not fitting to the screen output that is some numbers are outside of the plot. I am posting a screenshot of the issue below.

I even tried increasing figsize but the issue persists.

[image: Heatmap]

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Is there any temporary fix that I could use?

Comment: Yes, check the answer in the duplicate.